# How to get an element of a list , which is computed out of substituted variables?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, replacement

What is the best way to get the element of a list, which is computed out of substituded variables?

For example one wants to get the first element of the first row of

```
 (a A + a B) /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}}
```

Using

```
 (a A + a B)[[1,1]] /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}}
```

gives me:

```
2
```

I tried something like

```
elem[x_?MatrixQ, part__: All] := x[[part]];
```

But this makes the result only more disturbing...

This result should be able to be used in an other expression, where the substituion is done: For example:

```
temp = (a A+a B)[[1,1]];
temp + 3 /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}}
```

Last but not least: Is there also a possibility to hold other expressions? For Example:

```
temp1[x_] := (x a A + a B)[[1,1]] // Hold;
temp2 = NIntegrate[temp1[x],{0,1,x}] // Hold;
temp2 + 3 /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}} // ReleaseHold
```

?

Comment: @Kuba the result should be $2\cdot 1+2\cdot 8=18$

Comment: Without the factor $a$ mathematica gives the expected result $9$. But with a warning message.

Comment: @Kuba  Unfortunately I can not use your solution, because expression $(a A + a B)[[1,1]]$ is done inside a function, where the substitution not done.

Comment: @Kuba Look at the last example. How to write the first line to use $temp$ in a way like the second line. Without $a$ this would work fine.

Comment: `temp = Hold[(a A + a B)[[1, 1]]];
temp + 3 /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
   B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}} // ReleaseHold` ?

Comment: @Kuba Thanks! This looks like what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

```
exp = (a A + a B) /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
   B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}};
exp[[1, 1]]
```

The original code takes part [[1,1]] of the expression which is a, hence 2. Alternatively you could put parentheses around expression and rules and take part or

```
Part[(a A + a B) /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, 
   B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}}, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since **V10** you can play with `Inactivate` and `Activate`

```
x = a A + a B /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}} // Inactivate;

x[[1]]
```

[image]

```
x[[2]]
```

[image]

```
y = Activate[x, ReplaceAll]
```

[image]

```
z = Activate[y]
```

> {{18, 18}, {18, 18}}

```
z[[1, 1]]
```

> 18

**Or**, directly

```
Activate[x][[2, 2]]
```

> 18

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you believe your `elem` function does not work as it is just how I would approach this and it works as expected:

```
elem[x_?MatrixQ, part__: All] := x[[part]];

elem[(a A + a B), 1, 1] /. {a -> 2, A -> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, B -> {{8, 7}, {6, 5}}}
```

> ```
> 18
> ```