# Unexpected behavior from Indexed (threading and messages)

Tags: functions, core-language, index

I was going to include [`Indexed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Indexed.html) in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63511/121), thinking that it operated much as a `List`-only `Part` equivalent, but I ran into a surprise:

```
Indexed[(a A + a B), 1]
```

> During evaluation of In[13]:= Indexed::itv: a A is not a list or valid
>   tensor variable. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[13]:= Indexed::itv: a B is not a list or valid
>   tensor variable. >>
>
> ```
> Indexed[a A, {1}] + Indexed[a B, {1}]
> ```

1. Is it documented that `Indexed` threads over addition (`Plus`)?
2. What other heads does it thread over?
3. Since e.g. `a A` *can become* a list or tensor can this message be safely turned off?

Comment: Interesting. I managed to fully miss this function's introduction.

Comment: The documentation is very short and not explicit, as far as I can tell, but, isn't it implicit in the fact that is listed under *Symbolic Vectors* and in part when it says that `Indexed[x, n]` works like the n<sup>th</sup>  component of the symbolic vector `x`?

Comment: @rhermans Would you consider expounding on that in an answer?

Comment: Even if it was not documented, it makes sense for it to thread over addition; it reflects the property that the component of a sum of two tensors is the sum of the corresponding components of the two. It is weird that it complains about `Times[]`, since one can have the Hadamard product…

Comment: @J.M. By the same logic does it make sense for it to thread over anything else?  Pardon my ignorance.

Comment: I can't really think of any other operation it can be threaded on. Speaking of `Times[]` + `Indexed[]` weirdness, one would then expect `Indexed[p - q, j]` to expand appropriately, but it does not… oh well.

Comment: @J.M. It seems you were correct; see my self-answer.  Any idea about the apparently capricious `Indexed::itv` generation?

Comment: No idea at all; as I said, the one about `Times[]` is really weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Threading

Prompted by comments from J. M. I ran a brute-force check on `` System` `` Symbols to see if anything else threaded, or if this is a `Plus`-specific behavior.

```
Cases[
  Join @@ MakeExpression @ Names["System`*"],
  h_Symbol :> Head @ Indexed[Unevaluated @ h["a", "b"], {1}]
] // Quiet // Tally
```

> ```
> {{Indexed, 5474}, {String, 1}, {Plus, 1}}
> ```

So indeed it seems that `Plus` is unique as a head `Indexed` threads over.  `{String, 1}` comes from `List["a", "b"]`; everything else retains the head `Indexed`.

### Indexed::itv: message

I checked for the ***Indexed::itv: ... is not a list or valid tensor variable***  message as well.  I have not figured out what is special about these particular Symbols but maybe someone else can spot the pattern.

```
Cases[
  Join @@ MakeExpression @ Names["System`*"],
  h_Symbol :> 
    Check[Indexed[Unevaluated @ h["a", "b"], {1}], Sow @ Defer[h], Indexed::itv]
]; // Quiet // Reap // Last // Last
```

> ```
> {Abs, AiryAi, AiryAiPrime, AiryBi, AiryBiPrime, Alternatives, And, ArcCos, ArcCosh,
> ArcCot, ArcCoth, ArcCsc, ArcCsch, ArcSec, ArcSech, ArcSin, ArcSinh, ArcTan,
> ArcTanh, Arg, ArithmeticGeometricMean, Ball, BarnesG, BartlettHannWindow,
> BartlettWindow, BernsteinBasis, BesselI, BesselJ, BesselK, BesselY, Beta,
> BetaRegularized, Binomial, BlackmanHarrisWindow, BlackmanNuttallWindow,
> BlackmanWindow, BohmanWindow, Boole, BooleanRegion, BoundaryMeshRegion,
> BSplineBasis, CardinalBSplineBasis, CauchyWindow, Ceiling, ChebyshevT, ChebyshevU,
> Circle, Clip, Cone, ConicHullRegion, Conjugate, ConnesWindow, Cos, Cosh,
> CosineWindow, Cot, Coth, Csc, Csch, CubeRoot, Cuboid, Cylinder, DedekindEta,
> DirectedInfinity, DirichletWindow, DiscreteDelta, Disk, Divide, Element, Ellipsoid,
> EllipticE, EllipticF, EllipticK, EllipticPi, EllipticTheta, EllipticThetaPrime,
> EmptyRegion, Equal, Equivalent, Erf, Erfc, Erfi, ExactBlackmanWindow, Exists, Exp,
> ExpIntegralE, ExpIntegralEi, Factorial, Factorial2, FactorialPower, Fibonacci,
> FlatTopWindow, Floor, ForAll, FractionalPart, FullRegion, Function, Gamma,
> GammaRegularized, GaussianWindow, GegenbauerC, Greater, GreaterEqual, Gudermannian,
> HalfLine, HalfPlane, HammingWindow, HankelH1, HankelH2, HannPoissonWindow,
> HannWindow, Haversine, HermiteH, Hexahedron, HurwitzLerchPhi, HurwitzZeta,
> Hypergeometric0F1, Hypergeometric0F1Regularized, Hypergeometric1F1,
> Hypergeometric1F1Regularized, Hypergeometric2F1, Hypergeometric2F1Regularized,
> HypergeometricU, If, Im, ImplicitRegion, Implies, Inequality, InfiniteLine,
> InfinitePlane, IntegerPart, Interval, InverseGudermannian, InverseHaversine,
> InverseTransformedRegion, JacobiP, JacobiZeta, KaiserBesselWindow, KaiserWindow,
> KelvinBei, KelvinBer, KelvinKei, KelvinKer, KroneckerDelta, LaguerreL,
> LanczosWindow, LegendreP, LegendreQ, LerchPhi, Less, LessEqual, Line, Log, Log10,
> Log2, LogBarnesG, LogGamma, LogIntegral, LogisticSigmoid, LucasL, Majority,
> MathieuC, MathieuCharacteristicA, MathieuCharacteristicB,
> MathieuCharacteristicExponent, MathieuCPrime, MathieuS, MathieuSPrime, Max,
> MeshRegion, Min, Minus, Mod, Multinomial, Nand, Negative, NonNegative, NonPositive,
> Nor, Not, NotElement, NuttallWindow, Or, ParabolicCylinderD, Parallelepiped,
> Parallelogram, ParametricRegion, ParzenWindow, Piecewise, Plus, Pochhammer, Point,
> PoissonWindow, PolyGamma, Polygon, PolyLog, Positive, Power, PrimePi, Prism,
> ProductLog, Pyramid, QBinomial, QFactorial, QGamma, QHypergeometricPFQ,
> QPochhammer, QPolyGamma, Quantity, Quotient, QuotientRemainder, RankedMax,
> RankedMin, Re, Rectangle, RegionBoundary, RegionDifference, RegionIntersection,
> RegionProduct, RegionSymmetricDifference, RegionUnion, Rescale, RiemannSiegelTheta,
> RiemannSiegelZ, Root, Round, SawtoothWave, Sec, Sech, Sign, Simplex, Sin, Sinc,
> Sinh, Sphere, SphericalBesselJ, SphericalBesselY, SphericalHankelH1,
> SphericalHankelH2, SphericalHarmonicY, SpheroidalEigenvalue, SpheroidalPS,
> SpheroidalPSPrime, SpheroidalQS, SpheroidalQSPrime, SpheroidalS1,
> SpheroidalS1Prime, SpheroidalS2, SpheroidalS2Prime, Sqrt, SquareWave, StruveH,
> StruveL, Subtract, Surd, Switch, Tan, Tanh, Tetrahedron, Times, TransformedRegion,
> Triangle, TriangleWave, TukeyWindow, Unequal, UnitBox, UnitStep, UnitTriangle,
> WelchWindow, Which, WhittakerM, WhittakerW, Xnor, Xor, Zeta}
> ```