# Getting Part::partd and Part::partw messages in the following example

Tags: mathematical-optimization

```
sol1[t_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[{a + b - t == 0, a - b - 1 == 0}, 
   {{a, 0.80, 0.95}, {b, 0.95, 2}}];

a0[t_] := sol1[t][[1, 2]]; 
b0[t_] := sol1[t][[2, 2]];
f[t_] := 5 + a0[t] - b0[t]^2;

Print[sol1[1][[1, 2]]];

max0 := NMaximize[f[t], t];
Print[max0];

max1 := FindMaximum[f[t], {t, 2}];
Print[max1];

Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: You don't really need `FindRoot[]` for a linear equation, y'know.

Comment: Your code is somewhat unclear and it should be possible to simplify it considerably. Why don't you tell us what you are trying to accomplish instead?

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [(14645)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14645/121), [(21662)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21662/121), [(34554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34554/121), [(63407)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63407/121)

Answer (score 1):

By defining `sol1[t_?NumericQ] :=` you will cause a symbolic argument to be held:

```
sol1[foo]    (* out:   sol1[foo]   *)
```

You can therefore *not* extract parts from it that do not exist.  You should therefore make functions that call `sol1` *also* hold symbolic arguments:

```
ClearAll[a0, b0]

a0[t_?NumericQ] := sol1[t][[1, 2]];
b0[t_?NumericQ] := sol1[t][[2, 2]];
```

Now symbolic arguments do not evaluate, but numeric ones do:

```
a0[foo]
a0[3.7]
```

> ```
> a0[foo]
>
> 2.35
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following rewrite of your code.

1. Find a generic solution to your system of linear equations:

   ```
   solution = Solve[{a + b - t == 0, a - b - 1 == 0}, {a, b}]
   (* Out: {{a -> (1 + t)/2, b -> 1/2 (-1 + t)}} *)
   ```
2. Define a function involving those solutions; no need to define it with `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in this case. Simple `Set` (`=`) will do fine here.

   ```
   f[t_] = 5 + a - b^2 /. First@solution
   (* Out: 5 - 1/4 (-1 + t)^2 + (1 + t)/2 *)
   ```
3. Obtain the value of $t$ for which the function $f$ achieves its maximum value. The calculation can be done symbolically:

   ```
   maximum = ArgMax[f[t], t]
   (* Out: 2 *)
   ```
4. Plot the function `f` and the position of the maximum to check:

   ```
   Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 5}, 
     Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{maximum, f[maximum]}]}
   ]
   ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the help. This example represents a much bigger (non-linear) program, and was only meant to show the problem (getting the error messages). Please focus solely on this issue, and not on rectifying the code which is irrelevant per-se!